# Reading a csv file as a spark dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I have got a CSV file along with a header which has to be read through Spark(2.0.0 and Scala 2.11.8) as a dataframe.

Sample csv data:

```
Item,No. of items,Place
abc,5,xxx
def,6,yyy
ghi,7,zzz
.........
```

I'm facing problem when I try to read this csv data in spark as a dataframe, because the header contains column(No. of items) having special character "."

Code with which I try to read csv data is:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkExample")
import spark.implicits._    
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file:///INPUT_FILENAME")
```

Error I'm facing:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to resolve No. of items given [Item,No. of items,Place];
```

If I remove the `"."` from the header, I wont get any error. Even tried with escaping the character,but it escapes all the `"."` characters even from the data.

Is there any way to escape the special character `"."` only from the CSV header using spark code?

Comment: I tried this code `spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(input).show()`  with **Spark 2.2**. It's displaying fine.

Comment: I tried your given code in my spark 2.0.0 and still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: maybe, error not during reading, but in later processing?

Comment: I agree with @pasha701, are you sure you are getting the error in the reading part? please recheck and confirm.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of columns then just skip the header and provide the schema separately.

Comment: I've got a lot of columns in my csv.So providing schema separately is a difficult task.

Comment: I'm getting error while reading the csv through spark code.It's not able to form a dataframe itself.

Comment: @PoojaNayak This was a bug in spark-csv before it was merged with spark. (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/203)

Comment: So isn't there any other wau to read csv data with such header formats?

Comment: @PoojaNayak, You can skip the header as (philanthrovert) suggested. It is probably the easiest of all.

Comment: As there are more number of columns,I prefer to edit those columns which have a "." character in it.Anyways thanks for your suggestion @philanthrovert and saitejalakkimsetty.

Answer (score 2):

@Pooja Nayak, Not sure if this was solved; answering this in the interest of community.

```
sc: SparkContext
spark: SparkSession
sqlContext: SQLContext

// Read the raw file from localFS as-is.
val rdd_raw = sc.textFile("file:///home/xxxx/sample.csv")

// Drop the first line in first partition because it is the header.
val rdd = rdd_raw.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(idx,iter) => 
                      if(idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter
}

// A function to create schema dynamically.
def schemaCreator(header: String): StructType = {
  StructType(header
              .split(",")
              .map(field => StructField(field.trim, StringType, true))
  )
}

// Create the schema for the csv that was read and store it.
val csvSchema: StructType = schemaCreator(rdd_raw.first)

// As the input is CSV, split it at "," and trim away the whitespaces.
val rdd_curated = rdd.map(x => x.split(",").map(y => y.trim)).map(xy => Row(xy:_*))

// Create the DF from the RDD.
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_curated, csvSchema)
```

`import`s that are necessary

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark._
```

Answer (score -1):

I am giving you example which is working with pyspark, hopefully same will work for you, just by adding some language related syntax.

```
file =r'C:\Users\e5543130\Desktop\sampleCSV2.csv'   
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('FICBOutputGenerator')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.options(delimiter=",", header="true").csv("cars.csv")   #Without deprecated API
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load("cars.csv")
```

Comment: I have tried with your solution but unable to resolve the issue,I'm still facing the same error.